# How to animate a scatterplot and a line graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate a scatter-plot and a line graph in parallel using `matplotlib`.

First, I plot the two pieces separately:

```
deaths_scatter = ax.scatter(all_episode_labels_list, all_episode_deaths_list, picker=5, label="Deaths")
death_line = ax.plot(all_episode_labels_list, all_episode_deaths_list)
```

Next, I set the visible window to the first range desired.

```
ax.axis([-.2, 9.5, -0.1, 12])
```

Finally, I define the update and animation functions, which should slowly pan the x-axis. This part works with just the scatter-plot...

```
def update(frames):

    ax.axis([frames, frames + 10, -0.1, 12])
    return deaths_scatter, 


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=list(range(0,80)), interval=1000, blit=True)
```

...but If I add the line graph it breaks

```
def update(frames):

    ax.axis([frames, frames + 10, -0.1, 12])
    return deaths_scatter, death_line,

 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_zorder'
```

I've attempted to search overflow and the web for a solution, but I haven't had any luck yet. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `death_line, = ax.....`

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate on that? (Also sorry for the duplicate, I couldn't find any questions. Could you link the duplicate?)~ @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: You just need a comma between `death_line` and `= ax.plot(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I can't upvote your comment, and there's no answer to give a green check to. Is there something else I can do to improve your rep?@ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: The question is marked as duplicate. You can upvote the duplicate question and/or answer. No need to give any reputation to me.